# Probability that the Series ends in $6$ games in the World series.

Tags: probability

> In the World Series,two teams play each other repeatedly until one
>   team has won a total of $4$ games, then the Series ends. If each team
>   is equally likely to win each game,what is the probability that the
>   Series ends in exactly $6$ games.

I am having some difficulty applying the formulas for conditional probability and understanding what's going on all the time.

Intuitively,this is how I would tackle the problem without any formulas.

Let $X,Y$ be the two teams playing.

Now,for the World Series to finish in $6$ games we can have two cases :

i)X loses first $2$ games,then wins the other $4$.

ii)Y loses first $2$ games,then wins the other $4$.

I am told that the probability that $X$ or $Y$ wins is equal so that $X,Y$ have both $\frac{1}{2}$ chance to win (or loose).

For (i) I have to realise the sequence $L-L-W-W-W-W$ so I have $\cfrac{1}{2}\cdot\cfrac{1}{2}\cdot\cfrac{1}{2}\cdot\cfrac{1}{2}\cdot\cfrac{1}{2}\cdot\cfrac{1}{2}=\left(\cfrac{1}{2}\right)^6$

The case (ii) is the same so I have again $\left(\cfrac{1}{2}\right)^{6}$

So the total probability is $2\left(\cfrac{1}{2}\right)^{6} \approx \cfrac{3}{100}$

This is I would think about it without any formulas(so I think my solution is uncorrect),altough I would like to see how I should apply them and the reason behind.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if X loses the second and fourth game but wins every other game?

Comment: Right,didn't think about that.Problem is even harder then.

Comment: Just curious, is this from the book Understanding Probability by Tijms?

Comment: @Ritz I've taken this problem from Art of problem solving,II volume (p.222,ex n^ 308)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first mistake was to assume that, for example, $X$
has to $LLWWWW$. That is not the only case, for example they could still have $LWLWWW$. The correct condition is that $X$ has to win the series on the 6th game.

So, regarding $X$, the probability that they win is $p = .5$. They must win exactly 3 games in 5 trials. Recognize that you have $n=5$ presumably independent trials. Thus, this is a binomial distribution  on the first 5 games. Then they have to win one more on the 6th, so
$$P(X\text{ wins on 6th}) = P(X \text{ wins 3 in 5})P(X\text{ wins 6th game}) = \binom{5}{3}(.5)^3(.5)^2\times .5.$$
This is just the probability that $X$ wins. For the series to end in 6 games, either $X$ wins on sixth or $Y$ wins on sixth. Since they cannot both win on sixth, these are disjoint events and so

\begin{align*}
P(\text{Series ends on 6th})&=P(X\text{ wins on 6th})+P(Y\text{ wins on 6th}) \\
&= 2P(X\text{ wins on 6th}) \\
&=2\binom{5}{3}(.5)^3(.5)^2\times .5\\ 
&= \frac{5}{16}.
\end{align*}